# ProRes444 Codec download process to Adobe Media Encoder

Tags: after-effects, codec, adobe-media-encoder, prores

I am using MacOS Sierra and am trying to download the ProRes444 Codec in order to export my Adobe After Effects 4k RED footage in this format (probably using Adobe Media Encoder based on what I have seen others do). I found a download of 'pro video formats' that supposedly includes this codec, and downloaded a trial of final cut pro so that it could run ProRes444 on my computer, but am not sure how to find it in Media Encoder now. Are there other steps I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: This question is confusing.  Media Encoder and After Effects are part of the Adobe world.  FCPX is part of Apple world.  Media Encoder doesn't really talk to FCPX at all.

Comment: @MichaelTiemann I only downloaded FCPX because ProRes4444 (as Bobby Circle pointed out it is actually called) wouldn't download onto my computer unless I had FCPX already installed (or a few other programs, none of them Adobe) . I asked my acquaintance who recommended ProRes4444 and they confirmed that I would need FCPX order to download the codec. Does this seem wrong to you? It does seem strange that I couldn't download it with Adobe but could use it with Adobe afterwards...

Comment: A workaround is to render to a lossless format, and then transcode to prores with something like ffmpeg. It works for windows users when clients demand prores encoded files.

Comment: To clarify: you do not download the codec. Installing FCP installs the codecs. The standalone codec download is for people who only wish to **play** ProRes files. You want the ability to **encode** ProRes files as well. Once you install FCP you should see the ProRes codec(s) in all apps, including Adobe apps. If you are not seeing them, something else is wrong.

Comment: Try Cineform or DNxHR. ProRes is so 2007.

Answer (score 1):

In Media Encoder you first need to select your destination format as Quicktime. From there you should be able to find ProRes 4444.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you mean [ProRes444**4**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_ProRes#ProRes_4444_and_ProRes_4444_XQ).

As I understand the general situation, and as you also imply in your question, one needs to install FCP in order to encode with the indispensible ProRes codecs in other apps (such as Adobe ones.) That's certainly what I've gotten used to doing on brand new machines. I'm not sure if the *trial* version of FCP would do the trick, but I don't see why not. I don't think there's a stand-alone installer of the ProRes codecs, at least not for encoding. It's probably just for decoding (i.e., playback of a pre-existing ProRes video.) Someone correct me if I'm wrong here.

Okay, so let's assume the ProRes codecs are successfully installed (for encoding, not merely decoding) on your machine. In Media Encoder, you can export using Presets, or you can export using custom settings. You want the latter. [Check out this link](https://helpx.adobe.com/media-encoder/using/encode-export-video-audio.html#encode_using_custom_settings) to see the various ways to access the custom Export Settings. (I usually just click on the pre-assigned preset name to open the custom Export Settings dialog window.)

Once you get the custom Export Settings window open, you'll need to change the Format option to ProRes4444. If you don't see any ProRes formats in that dropdown list, they may not be installed properly yet. You can also check to see if the codecs are currently installed for encoding from AE without firing up Media Encoder. Just add an item to the render queue and try to customize the output format. If you don't see any ProRes codecs available in AE, you probably won't see any in Media Encoder.